# Does finite fourth moment imply finite third absolute moment?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

This may be a silly question, but, for a random variable $X$ defined on reals, I am wondering if the existence of the finite fourth central moment $E[(X-E[X])^4]$ implies the existence of the finite third absolute moment $E[|X-E[X]|^3]$?  Formally, does the following statement hold:

$$E[(X-E[X])^4]<\infty\Rightarrow E[|X-E[X]|^3]<\infty$$

The reason for my question is that, while trying to apply the [Berry-Esseen Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) to bound the total variation distance between the distribution of the (appropriately normalized) mean of $n$ i.i.d. random variables and the standard normal distribution, I am finding that the fourth central moment of the i.i.d. random variables the distribution of whose average is being approximated is much easier to compute than their third absolute moment...

Comment: This works because the measure of the space is finite.  When integrating over spaces of infinite measure, this doesn't hold.

Comment: I am not that familiar with measure theory, but all probability measures are finite, correct?  And thanks for fixing the typo in my question.

Comment: Probability measures are finite.  But in some other contexts than probability theory one integrates over spaces of infinite measure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Yes.

Proof: Apply the inequality $|x|^3\leqslant1+x^4$ to $x=X-E[X]$ and integrate.

Comment: This is a very pretty answer, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to bound $|x|^3$ by a polynomial involving $x^4$ and $x$?

I just wonder how you come up with these inequalities.

Comment: @Glassjawed $|x|^3\leqslant x^4+|x|$. Just draw the graphs of all these functions on, say, $(-5,5)$.

Answer (score 7):

Split the random variable into the following regions

1. $ |X - E[X]| > 1 $. In this region, $|X-E[X]|^3 < |X-E[X]|^4$
2. $|X - E[X]| \leq 1$. In this region, $|X-E[X]|^3 \leq 1 $.

Hence conclude that $E\left[|X-E[X]|^3\right] < E\left[|X-E[X]|^4\right] + 1$