# Berry-Esseen Theorem-like result with fourth central moment instead of third absolute moment

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

Let $X_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ be i.i.d. random variables with $E[X_i]=\mu$, $E[(X_i-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2$, and $E[(X_i-\mu)^4]=\kappa$.  I am interested in approximating the distribution of $Y_n=\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{\sqrt{n}\sigma}$ by the standard normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.  By [Berry-Esseen Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) we know that the total variation distance between the c.d.f. $F_n(x)$ of $Y_n$ and the c.d.f. $\Phi(x)$ of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is upper-bounded as follows:

$$\tag{1}|F_n(x)-\Phi(x)|\leq \frac{C\rho}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}}$$

where $\rho=E[|X_i-\mu|^3]$ is the absolute third moment of $X_i$ and $C$ is a constant.

In my particular problem, the fourth central moment $E[(X_i-\mu)^4]$ is much easier to compute than the third absolute moment $E[|X_i-\mu|^3]$.  While the $E[(X_i-\mu)^4]$ provides a ready upper bound for $E[|X_i-\mu|^3]$ per answers to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464390/does-finite-fourth-moment-imply-finite-third-absolute-moment), which I can just plug into (1), obtaining same asymptotics, I am wondering if there is a tighter result than that, specific to the fourth central moment.

Comment: Actually, $E[|X_i-\mu|^3]\leqslant E[(X_i-\mu)^4]^{3/4}$ by convexity, and this upper bound is optimal.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply (and yet another bound on the third absolute moment -- I don't know how I forgot about the Jensen's Inequality).  However, could you please elaborate on your statement about optimality: why is the Berry-Esseen bound with the upper bound to third moment plugged in optimal?  Is there a proof that there is no better bound on the third absolute moment using fourth central moment?

Comment: Try $X_i$ symmetric Bernoulli.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz might give you what you want. Consider $$|E(AB)| \le E(A^2)^{1/2} E(B^2)^{1/2}$$
with $A=|X_i-\mu|$ and $B = (X_i-\mu)^2$. Then you get the inequality
$$E(|X_i-\mu|^3) \le \sigma \kappa^{1/2}, $$
which might be better for your application. Or you could use Hölder's inequality as suggested in the comments and get the upper bound $\kappa^{3/4}$. Both of these inequalities will be tight in general since Cauchy-Schwarz and Hölder are tight.